Inputs are not saved in Next.js with Prisma and ShadCN dialog and are not added to the realtion prisma model
I am working on a Next.js application where users can add feature cards to a product. I'm using Prism as the ORM to store the product and its associated data (including the feature cards), and the ShadCN dialog component to provide the input fields for the feature cards. I have implemented a form for creating and editing products that also supports feature cards. However, the feature card is neither saved nor added to the product when a new product is created.
Problem:
When creating a product with a feature card, the product is saved but the feature card is not added.
When editing a product, no feature cards are displayed, even if they were previously saved in the product.
I don't get any errors, but the data doesn't seem to be saved or linked correctly.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
I tried to get the featureCards from the form and create them in my prisma with this code:
  // Feature Cards
  const featureCardsData = formData.getAll("featureCards") as string[];
  const featureCards = featureCardsData.map((cardString) => {
    const card = JSON.parse(cardString); // Feature Cards als JSON
    const imagePath = `products/${crypto.randomUUID()}-${card.image.name}`;
    fs.writeFile(`public/${imagePath}`, Buffer.from(card.image)); // Bild speichern
    return {
      name: card.name,
      description: card.description,
      imagePath,
    };
  });


  const accessoryIds = formData.getAll("accessories") as string[];

  await db.product.create({
    data: {
      isAvailableForPurchase: false,
      name: data.name,
      description: data.description,
      priceInCents: data.priceInCents,
      filePath,
      imagePath,
      addimagePath1,
      addimagePath2,
      addimagePath3,
      categoryId: data.categoryId,
      groupId: data.groupId,
      accessories: {
        connect: accessoryIds.map((id) => ({ id })), // Nur gültige IDs verbinden
      },
      featureCards: {
        create: featureCards,
      },
    },
    include: { accessories: true, featureCards: true },
  });

